# What's the Best Way to Import This GICS Table from the Web?

Tags: import, html, table

I am trying to import this table from Wikipedia and create a dataset:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard

```
GICS = Import[
   "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_\
Standard", "Data"];
```

is a useful start, but the table structure is hierarchical and difficult to massage into a dataset structure.

Does anyone have any useful tips or suggestions on how best to proceed?